# Environment switching command is not working as documented in karate 0.7.0

Tags: karate

In the "Switching Environment" section of https://github.com/intuit/karate the following command is listed to select the  environment within the karate-config.js:

mvn test -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=mock"

That results in karate.env being null.

If you modify the command as follows the variable is set:

mvn test -Dkarate.env=mock

I'm using 0.7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's news to me. Probably due to the Maven version. Can you be clear about your OS version and Maven version and raise an issue to fix the doc. Do note that no one has ever reported this.

EDIT: Also, it is quite likely your maven `pom.xml` has a `<properties>` entry with the key `<karate.env>` and **that** is why you are seeing this behavior !

Comment: This is using the demo project (and my own project). Neither have karate.env.
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-25T05:49:05+10:00)
Maven home: C:\tim\apache-maven-3.5.3-bin\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_162, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre
Default locale: en_AU, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: ok, I have no option but to point you to this page: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Yes, I've read that. My reading of it is to raise the issue here first and then on then optionally on github. (sorry about the quick comment submit, getting used to having to shift-enter for comments and just enter for raising issues on stack overflow)

Comment: no worries. given the info above I am unable to act on this. worth mentioning that I don't consider the karate demo as a "representative" project, because it does all kinds of weird stuff in the `karate-config.js` for example. which is why do create a simple hello-world and if you still see this, please submit an issue

Comment: I created a small project and can set karate.env both ways. I'll close this and investigate what exactly is breaking it for the demo and my main project.

Comment: In addition to not working `-DargLine="-Dkarate.env=e2e` for me, I found `-Dkarate.env=test` will not work in powershell too, so I changed my terminal into CMD to execute tests in specific environment