# karate.env selected environment was: null

Tags: maven, karate

I am setting maven parameter as

```
mvn test -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=QA"
```

but getting below error while running

```
karate.env selected environment was: null
```

Comment: I used -DKarate.env instead of -Dkarate.env and that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can try `mvn test -Dkarate.env=QA`

If that does not work, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks for your response but it is still not working. Can you pls suggest ?

Comment: no, you can read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50690543/143475 - and I already suggested what you should do above. or get someone who knows maven well to help you.

Comment: I found a workaround seems there was an issue with my maven command. This is closed.